# What is the difference between the Selenium tool and the Cypress tool?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cypress

What is the difference between the Selenium tool and Cypress tool? How they both are works differently from each other?

Answer (score 0):

> First, Cypress is said to have an easier onboarding than Selenium,
>   where all you need to do is install the .exe to get up and running
>   sine all the drivers and dependencies are automatically installed.
>   With Selenium, on the other hand, you need to spend a little more time
>   getting everything up and running.
>
> One of the advantages of Selenium is that it supports most of the
>   major programming languages including Java, Perl PHP, Python, Ruby,
>   and C#, so if your team is already using one of those languages,
>   Cypress may not be ideal since it only supports JavaScript.
>
> In addition, since Cypress tests are written using Mocha and Chai, the
>   syntax echoes what most Javascript users understand. This means that
>   if you work with Javascript, it will be especially easy to start using
>   Cypress. However, if you’re more familiar with another language, it
>   will be fairly complex.
>
> Cypress almost acts as a “freemium” model. Similiar to Selenium which
>   is entirely open sourced unless you integrate with a paid tool, you
>   can also add to Cypress’s core capabilities by leveraging the paid
>   dashboard which includes a test runner that allows you to easily debug
>   tests with DOM snapshots and includes video storage for private
>   projects.
>
> Selenium and Cypress differ in the way of their architecture, as well.
>   Selenium is made up of bindings, or libraries, and the WebDriver,
>   which controls the browsers. These two components work through the
>   JSON network.
>
> Alternatively, while Cypress is used for UI testing, it uses its own
>   unique DOM manipulation and runs directly in the browser with no
>   network communication. Cypress is often cited as a developer-friendly
>   test automation tool for this reason since this often causes
>   frustrations for them in Selenium.
>
> Having a different architecture on top of an Electron app also allows
>   Cypress to be so close to the web application under test that we can
>   do things that you can’t do in Selenium such as stubbing DOM APIs.
>
> One of the biggest gaps between Selenium and Cypress is that while
>   Selenium runs against different browsers, as mentioned before, Cypress
>   only supports Chrome. Selenium’s browser support is often integral to
>   those who use it, making Cypress severely lacking in the area of
>   cross-browser testing.
>
> For software teams that find importance in checking their website on
>   multiple browsers instead of just leaving their code up to chance,
>   finding their way around this deficiency could prove challenging to
>   Cypress users.

Source: https://crossbrowsertesting.com/blog/test-automation/selenium-vs-cypress/

Which one to use is really based on requirements.

Comment: I didn't downvote but you more or less copy-pasted the answer, it would be better if you summarized it and gave a link to the original

Comment: Also, when you say "this is really a Google to do the question not to ask in Stack", why do you answer at all? Either the question is valuable, then answer (ideally with more than just a multi-line quote), or if it isn't, try to help the OP to improve the question or vote for it to be closed.

Comment: removed the intro